# pandas group StopIteration error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following on a group object:

- get the interarrival time
- set the range, flag with vectorized where
- get cumsum over interarrival time

  ```
  def deltat(g):
      try:
          g['tavg'] = g[ g['alert_v']==1 ]['timeindex'].diff(1)

          g['iqt'] = np.where( g['value'] > g['value'].quantile(.90) or g['value']< g['value'].quantile(.10),1,0)
          #pd.to_datetime(g[['tavg']], format='%H:%M:%S')
          #print type(g['tavg'] )

          g['cumt'] = g['tavg'].cumsum(0) #pd.rolling_sum(g['tavg'],2,0).shift(1)
          print g.head()
          return g
      except:
          pass

  d.sort_index(axis=0, inplace=True)
  d=d.groupby(['source','subject_id','alert_t','variable'],as_index=False,group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: deltat(x))
  ```

`error:`
I am getting a StopIteration error.  what causes this? why does the exception not just pass?

`cumsum`
Am I using cumsum correctly, or do I need to use a rolling_sum to get the sums over each subsequent two time values rows in the column?

-any help is appreciated

--edit:
here is some sample input:

```
 d = pd.DataFrame({'alert_v': [1]*4 + [0]*4,
              'value': np.random.rand(0,4)*3 + np.random.rand(0,4),
              'timeindex': pd.date_range(end='6/20/2012',periods=8)
             })
```

what I need is output with columns: 
`tavg` which is difference subsequent times where `alert_v` is 1.
`iqt` need to set 1 for any value above/below quantile levels or 0
`cumt` this is the cumulative sum of each subsequent tavg value, ie the cumsum

`alert_v   value   timeindex  tavg   iqt cumt
1           3.1      6/13     NaN    0   NaN
1           2.9      6/14     1      0   1
0           .3       6/15     Nan    0   NaN
1           3.3      6/16     2      0   3 
0           .3       6/17     NaN    0   NaN
0           .5       6/18     NaN    0   NaN
0           .2       6/19     NaN    1   NaN
1           3.8      6/20     4      1   7`

Attempts at vectorization just still produce the `StopIteration` error:

```
 `gg['cumt'] = gg.apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x['tavg'],2, min_periods=2).shift(1) )`
```

or
     `gg['cumt'] = gg.apply( lambda x: x['tavg'] + x['tavg'].shift(1)[1:] )`

For tavg and iqt, I use these two approaches, but in two different functions... putting them in one function caused a problem.

```
  g['tavg'] = g[ g['alert_v']==1 ]['timeindex'].diff(1)
  g['iqt'] = g['value'].map(lambda x: x > g['value'].quantile(.90) and 1 or x < g['value'].quantile(.10) and 1 or 0)
```

alert_v  value     tavg  iqt
timeindex
1984-12-12 13:33:00        0     86      NaT  NaN
1984-12-12 14:08:00        0     85      NaT    1
1984-12-12 14:08:00        0     85      NaT    1
1984-12-12 14:08:00        0     84      NaT    1
1984-12-12 14:08:00        0     84      NaT    1
1984-12-12 14:08:00        1     82      NaT    1
1984-12-12 14:25:00        1     83 00:17:00    1
1984-12-12 14:47:00        1     83 00:22:00    1
1984-12-12 16:37:00        0     88 01:50:00    1
1984-12-12 16:37:00        1     82 01:50:00    1
1984-12-12 16:37:00        0     90 01:50:00    1
1984-12-12 17:52:00        0     85 01:15:00    0
1984-12-12 17:52:00        1     95 01:15:00    0
1984-12-12 19:29:00        1     91 01:37:00    0
1984-12-12 19:29:00        0     95 01:37:00    0

anyhow, how do i take the cumsum over filtered rows ? (thanks for the vectorization tip)

Comment: pls show your input and what is the expected output, in a copy-pastable form. What you are doing is very inefficient. A groupby should try to use vectorized functions when possible. Then join them up at the end.

Comment: The stop iteration error might be due to not returning a dataframe in the except clause. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974759/stopiteration-error-when-using-groupby-method-of-pandas-dataframe