# StopIteration error when using groupby method of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a similar problem with the `groupby` method that this person has posted on StackOverflow:

[pandas group StopIteration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566377/pandas-group-stopiteration-error)

What I am trying to do with the `grouby` method is simpler, but I am getting a similar `StopIteration` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prepare_data_TJ2012_v1p0.py", line 107, in <module>
    grouped = df.groupby('hh').apply(f)
  File "/Users/shafiquejamal/allfiles/htdocs/venvs/easyframes-py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 637, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "/Users/shafiquejamal/allfiles/htdocs/venvs/easyframes-py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 644, in _python_apply_general
    not_indexed_same=mutated)
  File "/Users/shafiquejamal/allfiles/htdocs/venvs/easyframes-py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2657, in _wrap_applied_output
    v = next(v for v in values if v is not None)
StopIteration
```

Here is the code that produces it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'educ': {0: 'pri', 1: 'bach', 2: 'pri', 3: 'hi', 4: 'bach', 5: 'sec', 
                6: 'hi', 7: 'hi', 8: 'pri', 9: 'pri'}, 
             'hh': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 4}, 
             'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 4}, 
             'has_car': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}, 
             'weighthh': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3}, 
             'house_rooms': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3}, 
             'prov': {0: 'BC', 1: 'BC', 2: 'BC', 3: 'Alberta', 4: 'BC', 5: 'BC', 6: 'Alberta', 
                7: 'Alberta', 8: 'Alberta', 9: 'Alberta'}, 
             'age': {0: 44, 1: 43, 2: 13, 3: 70, 4: 23, 5: 20, 6: 37, 7: 35, 8: 8, 9: 15}, 
             'fridge': {0: 'yes', 1: 'yes', 2: 'yes', 3: 'no', 4: 'yes', 5: 'yes', 6: 'no', 
                7: 'no', 8: 'no', 9: 'no'}, 
             'male': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}})
print(df)
print('-- groupby dataframes ---')
def f(df):
    print('-------------------------')
    print('DataFrame' )
    print(df)
    s = df['age']
    print(s)
    print('----> Not nulls:')
    s_notnulls = ~s.isnull()
    print(s_notnulls)
    print('----> Number of non-nulls: %d' % len(s_notnulls[s_notnulls==True]))
df.groupby('hh').apply(f)
```

I want to perform an operation on a column, by group, if there is at least one non-null value in another column.

I'm using `pandas==0.14.1`. It seems that the loop over the groups goes too long. Is this a bug? (or maybe I'm using the `groupby` method wrong...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting this error because the function you are passing to apply doesn't return anything.  If all you care about is the printed output, you could just return the df back, like this.

```
def f(df):
    print('-------------------------')
    print('DataFrame' )
    print(df)
    s = df['age']
    print(s)
    print('----> Not nulls:')
    s_notnulls = ~s.isnull()
    print(s_notnulls)
    print('----> Number of non-nulls: %d' % len(s_notnulls[s_notnulls==True]))

    return df
```

Then the apply will run through without error.

```
In [295]: df.groupby('hh').apply(f)
-------------------------
DataFrame
   age  educ fridge  has_car  hh  house_rooms  id  male prov  weighthh
0   44   pri    yes        1   1            3   1     1   BC         2
1   43  bach    yes        1   1            3   2     0   BC         2
2   13   pri    yes        1   1            3   3     1   BC         2
.....
```